# Pgfplot's addplot3 `scatter` works, but `contour` says: "You have an axis with empty range (in direction z)"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In the following MWE, the `addplot3` scatter works with the provided data. The `contour` plot, however, throws the following:

```
Errors:
garden_heatmap.tex:38: Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{temp_contourtmp0.table} could not be opened. [...{x}, y={y}, z={frequency}] {\contourdata};]

Warnings:
garden_heatmap.tex: LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./contourdata.csv'.
garden_heatmap.tex: Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} into your preamble.
garden_heatmap.tex:38: Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been filtered away) on input line 38.
garden_heatmap.tex:40: Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction z). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots. on input line 40.
```

Here, the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{contourdata.csv}
x,y,frequency
0,0,1959
0,1,1906
0,2,1726
0,3,1753
0,4,1648
1,0,3328
1,1,2486
1,2,2109
1,3,1951
1,4,1785
2,0,2911
2,1,2508
2,2,2196
2,3,2048
2,4,1897
3,0,2396
3,1,2238
3,2,2104
3,3,2114
3,4,2084
4,0,2153
4,1,2198
4,2,2279
4,3,2249
4,4,2182
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{contourdata.csv}{\contourdata}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]%
%\addplot3[contour gnuplot={output point meta=rawz}, mesh/rows=5, mesh/cols=5] table[x={x}, y={y}, z={frequency}] {\contourdata};
\addplot3[only marks,scatter] table[x={x}, y={y}, z={frequency}] {\contourdata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

In consideration of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200278/47501) question:
I have gnuplot installed and shell-escape enabled.

Comment: Testing with PGFPlots v1.15 it works as expected. Which version do you have?

Comment: @StefanPinnow I'm using `Package: pgfplots 2016/08/10 v1.14 Data Visualization (1.14)`. Curiously, out of the blue now it works. However, I don't know what the problem was and I don't know what to do if it appears again.

Comment: Do you agree to delete your question (you have to do it) and if it should appear again that you again ask the question?

Comment: @StefanPinnow I would prefer if it stayed on so that other people with the same problem can find it and contribute to a solution.